# How to add hover tool to the add_layout in python bokeh?

Tags: python, hover, bokeh

I want to add a hover tool to an `Arrow` in `add_layout`. However, it seems that the hover tool does not add anything to it. Here is my code:

```
from bokeh.models import Arrow, VeeHead, ColumnDataSource, HoverTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

output_file("arrow.html", title="arrow.py example")

p = figure(plot_width=600, plot_height=600)
p.circle(x=[0, 1, 3], y=[0, 5, 0.7], radius=0.1,
     color=["navy", "yellow", "red"], fill_alpha=0.1)

data = ColumnDataSource({"x_start": [0],
                     "x_end": [2],
                     "y_start": [0],
                     "y_end": [1]})


p.add_layout(Arrow(end=VeeHead(size=35), line_color="red", x_start="x_start", y_start="y_start", x_end="x_end", y_end="y_end", source = data, name="arrow"))
hover_tool = HoverTool(tooltips=[('x_start', '@x_start'), ("x_end", "@x_end"), ("y_start", "@y_start")], names=["arrow"])
p.add_tools(hover_tool)

show(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrows are annotations, not glyphs, and do not support hit-testing. It is not possible to attach a hover tool to an arrow.